# How to expose dd-wrt localhost port to other clients on LAN?

Tags: router, dd-wrt

On my mac computer at work behind a corporate firewall, I ssh into my home dd-wrt router over the internet, creating a reverse tunnel:

```
ssh -R 1079:localhost:22 myhomepc.ddns.net
```

So now, when I'm home, I ssh into my home dd-wrt router, and I can log into my mac at work from the bash prompt on the dd-wrt router

```
ssh localhost -p 1079
```

That works. HOWEVER, what I really need is to log into my mac from another computer on my LAN, so I tried:

```
ssh 192.168.1.1 -p 1079
```

But this does not work. The question is:  How do I expose port 1079 on my dd-wrt router (192.168.1.1) so that other computers on my LAN can hit port 1079?

(FYI, here is the output from using telnet to try to hit the port from ubuntu)

```
root@ubuntu:~# telnet 192.168.1.1 1079
Trying 192.168.1.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to set up a **local port forward**, by sshing into the router and reforwarding port 1079 to something else on localhost.
example:

set up forward:

`ssh -L 22022:localhost:1079 192.168.1.1`

use forwarded port:

`ssh -p 22022 127.0.0.1`